# constant generics in function arguments

Tags: generics, rust, constants

I'm trying to write a function which works uses constant generics to select the size of an array. Using constant generics in the main function works like so.

```rust
fn main() {
    const N: usize = 100;
    // let primes = primes_up_to(10_000);
    let list = [1; N];
    print!("{:?}", list)
}
```

therefore to use a constant generic in a function I would expect:

```rust
fn const_generic_test(const LEN: usize) {
    let test_arr = [1, LEN];
    println!("{:?}", test_arr)
}
```

However, this doesn't work. How can I take a constant generic as a function argument?

Comment: "Using constant generics in the main function works like so." your example with main don't compile

Comment: apologies I copied from my program and accidentally missed the line  `const N: usize = 100;`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of constant generic is close to generic:

```rust
fn const_generic_test<const LEN: usize>() {
    let test_arr = [1, LEN];
    println!("{:?}", test_arr)
}
```